# User Third Party Module in Xcode Playground

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire library in Xcode Playground. So i followed this guide:

http://use-cocoapods-in-playground.blogspot.com/2015/09/use-cocoapods-in-playground.html

But i got this problem:

[image]

Did anyone get this trouble ? how can i solve it ?

Comment: Are you using the .xcworkspace file?

Comment: Yes i open .xcworkspace file after 'pod install'

Comment: Is it working in a regular project?

Comment: check this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16844. similar issue

Comment: The last post in this link say "This really sounds like the playground's not getting built for some reason. Perhaps it's not getting built for the simulator?
 
If you can, please file a bug report and attach the entire workspace."

It maybe a Xcode bug ? :(